# How can I extract elements from a transfer function matrix in Octave?

Tags: octave, transfer-function, control-theory

I am working with Octave in the control package, and I want to take an array of transfer functions (initialized as follows) and just extract the diagonal elements of the matrix. Whenever I try to do this, I run into the following error. I have tried lots of workarounds (converting it to a state space diagram, storing the elements in a cell, etc.), but I either run into a similar error or I end up with an object that can no longer interact with other matrices of transfer functions. There are some unimplemented functions (like ss2ss) in the documentation that I think would be useful but are unavailable.

How can I work around this?

The code initializing the type of object I'm working with:

```
s = tf('s');
m = inv(s*e - mat); // e and mat are just square matrices of numbers
```

The code I am using to try to extract the diagonal components:

```
function D = getD(W) // W is of the similar type as above
    n = size(W,1);
    Dtemp = tf(eye(n));
    for i = 1:n
        Dtemp(i,i) = W(i,i);
    end
    D = Dtemp;
end
```

Errors that I keep getting:

```
error: lti: subsasgn: invalid subscripted assignment type '()'.  you must select an LTI key first, i.e.  sys.keyname(...) = ...
```

**Note that when I initialized Dtemp as cell (n,n), I get this type:**

```
{
  [1,1] =

    <class tf>

  [2,1] =

    <class tf>
etc.
```

Instead of this type: (which is what I want it to interact with)

```
{
  [1,1] =

    <class tf>

}
```

Even though they are both nxn in size. I am hoping to be able to convert the former into the latter, so I can interact with other objects of the latter type.

Comment: Did you try `diag`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yeah, unfortunately the type doesn’t play well with the control package